# Mongoose: call a resolver in another resolver

Tags: mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

I have users subscribing to events :

```
const EventType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:'Event',
    fields:() => ({
        id: {type:GraphQLID}  
     })
});


const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:'User',
    fields:() => ({
        id: {type:GraphQLString},
        _subscriptionIds: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLID) },
        subscriptions: { 
            type: new GraphQLList(EventType),
            async resolve(parent, args) {
                return Event.find( {_id: { $in: parent._subscriptionIds}})
            }
         }
         anotherField: {
            type: new AnotherType,
            async resolve(parent, args) {
                console.log(parent.subscriptions) // parent.subscriptions is undefined, I need to resolve it.
            }               
     })
});
```

Long story short, I need to access parent.subscriptions (which are of type Event), in anotherField resolver. sort of "force call" the subscriptions resolver.

Is it possible and how ?

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally never call one resolver from another. If you have code that's common to two or more resolvers, you can extract that code into it's own function (and possible a separate module) and just call it from both resolvers.

So your code could look something like this:

```
subscriptions: { 
  type: new GraphQLList(EventType),
  async resolve(parent, args) {
    return getSubscriptionsByIds(parent._subscriptionIds)
  },
},
anotherField: {
  type: new AnotherType,
  async resolve(parent, args) {
    const subscriptions = await getSubscriptionsByIds(parent._subscriptionIds)
    // do something else with the subscriptions here
  },    
},
```

However, this will result in additional calls to your database unless you're already using DataLoader to batch calls like that. A better solution would be to move the subscription fetching logic up a level (i.e. whereever you're fetching your list of users). You can eagerly load the subscriptions using `populate` or `$lookup`, then they will be available through the `parent` argument inside every User field resolver.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will use populate to limit the database calls.